# How can I make only parts of an image links?

Tags: html

[Website in question (Purple tile at bottom right, green boxes are the targets.](http://test.minecraftred.co.uk/)

I have the following html using area tags to select the first green box however I can't click it as a link. I am using bootstrap if it makes any difference.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <img src="octa.png" usemap="#pmc">
  <map name="pmc">
    <area shape="rect" coords="978,482,1038,512" alt="pmc" href="www.google.com">
  </map>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: is the image a descendant of an a or button element, You can't use USEMAP on these ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include multiple areas in your imagemap.

```
<img src="octa.png" usemap="#map" />

<map name="map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="51,47,112,77"  href="..." title="PMC Post" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="188,47,249,77" href="..." title="Direct Download" />
</map>
```

Comment: Thanks, I see where I was going wrong - I was measuring coords from top right of website.

Comment: From the top/right of your rendered page?  Yes, that would be a problem, especially if you resize your browser window.  :-)  You might also want to consider doing this in CSS.  There are tutorials all over the internet, [here's one](http://www.tankedup-imaging.com/css_dev/rollover.html) I bookmarked a while back.

Comment: I meant left, I don't know where I go right from :P

Answer (score 0):

you can use relative and absolute css properties

```
<div style="position:relative;">
  <a href="#" class="links" id="item1"></a>
  <a href="#" class="links" id="item2"></a>
  <img src="src/of/img.png" />
</div>
```

css side

```
.links {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
}
```